# Screen of iOS simulator or iPhone freeze when i want choose an image in image library

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller, freeze

I work on xcode 4.2 for ios 5 and  i test  little application on iphone 4S.
ARC and no storyboard.
I try to create an application to learn and so i test an application with a first view  menu(xib file with just one button who downloads the second view , HHKMenuViewController.h and .m) ,and a second view (xib file with UIImage and two buttons, HHKListViewController.h and .m). The second view it's here to give  the possibility for the user to take an image in the image library (first button) or to come back in the first view menu (second button).

That's work.No error. I compile on iOS simulator and i have the menu who appears. When i click on the button i go in the second view and i can choose my picture when i click on the button "choose picture" and this picture appears in the frame for the image in the second view. All it's ok.

BUT WHEN I MAKE first view-> second view (click on button back)-> first view ... about 10 times when i want to go in the image library the iOS simulator freeze (Xcode with no error) and i can't do anything. This is the same on my iPhone 4s. I try to see the activity of the memory with instruments (developer tools) but I see nothing wrong in relation to other applications.

Do you have a suggestion?

Thank you for your help.

-----------HHKAppDelegate.h------------------

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class HHKMenuViewController;

@interface HHKAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) HHKMenuViewController *menuViewController;

@end
```

-----------HHKAppDelegate.m-------------------

```
    #import "HHKAppDelegate.h"
#import "HHKMenuViewController.h"

@implementation HHKAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize menuViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch
    self.menuViewController = [[HHKMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HHKMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIView *menuView = self.menuViewController.view;
    [self.window addSubview:menuView];   
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

---------HHKMenuViewController.h---------------

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <mach/mach.h>
@class HHKListViewController;
@class HHKMenuViewController;

@interface HHKMenuViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) HHKListViewController *listViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) HHKMenuViewController *menuViewController;

- (IBAction)listButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

--------HHKMenuViewController.m----------------

```
#import "HHKMenuViewController.h"
#import "HHKListViewController.h"

@implementation HHKMenuViewController

@synthesize listViewController;
@synthesize menuViewController;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    self.listViewController = nil;}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.listViewController = nil;}

- (IBAction)listButtonPressed:(id)sender {

self.menuViewController = [[HHKMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HHKMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
UIView *menuView = self.menuViewController.view; 

self.listViewController = [[HHKListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HHKListViewController" bundle:nil];
UIView *listView = self.listViewController.view;

[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.75 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
animations:^{[menuView removeFromSuperview];[self.view insertSubview:listView aboveSubview:menuView];} 
                completion:NULL];}
@end
```

----------HHKListViewController.h-----------------

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@class HHKMenuViewController;
@class HHKListViewController;

@interface HHKListViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) HHKMenuViewController *menuViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) HHKListViewController *listViewController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *lastChosenMediaType;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect imageFrame;

-(IBAction)backMenuList:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)selectExistingPicture:(id)sender;

@end
```

----------HHKListViewController.m------------------

```
#import "HHKListViewController.h"
#import "HHKMenuViewController.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <mach/mach.h>

@interface HHKListViewController ()
static UIImage *shrinkImage(UIImage *original, CGSize size);
-(void)updateDisplay;
-(void)getMediaFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType;
@end

@implementation HHKListViewController

@synthesize menuViewController;
@synthesize listViewController;
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize image;
@synthesize lastChosenMediaType;
@synthesize imageFrame;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageFrame = imageView.frame;}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self updateDisplay];}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.imageView = nil;
    self.listViewController = nil;}

-(IBAction)backMenuList:(id)sender {

    self.menuViewController = [[HHKMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HHKMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIView *menuView = self.menuViewController.view; 
    self.listViewController = [[HHKListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HHKListViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIView *listView = self.listViewController.view;
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.75 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                    animations:^{
                        [listView removeFromSuperview];
                        [self.view insertSubview:menuView aboveSubview:listView];
                    } 
                    completion:NULL];}

- (IBAction)selectExistingPicture:(id)sender {

    [self getMediaFromSource:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#pragma mark UIImagePickerController delegate methods

-(void)imagePickerController :(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        UIImage *shrunkenImage = shrinkImage(chosenImage, imageFrame.size);
        self.image = shrunkenImage;
     [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; }


-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}

#pragma mark -

static UIImage *shrinkImage(UIImage *original, CGSize size) {
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width * scale,size.height * scale, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(context,CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width * scale, size.height * scale),original.CGImage);
    CGImageRef shrunken = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *final = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shrunken];
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(shrunken);   
    return final;}

-(void)updateDisplay {
    imageView.image = image;
    imageView.hidden = NO;}

- (void)getMediaFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {

     NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:sourceType];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType] && [mediaTypes count] > 0) {
        NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:sourceType];
        UIImagePickerController *picker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = sourceType;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error accessing media" message:@"Device doesn’t support that media source." 
                              delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Drat!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];}}

@end
```

Comment: It's too much code to analyze. You should narrow the area of investigation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the appdelegate.m

```
#import "HHKAppDelegate.h"
#import "HHKMenuViewController.h"

@implementation HHKAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES   withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
HHKMenuViewController *menuViewController = [[HHKMenuViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"HHKMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]   initWithRootViewController:menuViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```